# What would a Database Diagram (ER Diagram/Table Layout) look like for measuring distribution of something?

Tags: sql-server, database, statistics

If I was, for example, going to *count* "activities" across many computers and show a rollup of that activity, what would the database look like to store the data?

Simply this? Seems too simple. I'm overthinking this.

```
ACTIVITYID  COUNT
----------  -----
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the volume is not going to be ridiculously large, I'd probably create a table that logs each event individually, with a DateTime as @Turnkey suggests, and possibly the machine that logged it, etc.

```
LOGID (PK)  ACTIVITYID  SOURCE  DATELOGGED
----------  ----------  ------  ----------
```

That would give you the ability to run a query to get the current count, and also to use the data to determine events in a time period, and/or coming from a specific machine.  A clustered index on ActivityID should give you good query performance, and the table is narrow so inserts shouldn't be too costly.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the actual activity would create some type of record with at least an ActivityId and ActivityDate in a logging table.  An other column might be the identifier of the computer creating the log entry.

You would then create the count by aggregating the activity records over a specified time period.

Metro.

Comment: This would allow for better reporting, graphing etc that everyone loves to see.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm afraid it's that simple, assuming you are only interested in the number of times each activity occurs.  Once you have that table populated, you could easily create, for example, a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) of the results by sorting on count and plotting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add a DateTime field so that you can do reports of the events in between a certain time interval, or at least know when the last activity count was taken.

Comment: Yes, other fields such as ComputerID, UserID, etc. could be added if those dimensions were needed.